# Window.Load Not working on asp.net PostBack

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I'm trying to get the height/width of an image using JQuery.
It won't work until the image is fully loaded by using `$(window).load`.
When doing an asp.net UpdatePanel, the events are unbind from the elements. I've tried using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to call a Javascript function to bind all of the events again, but it won't run the `$(window).load`. Please help.

External JS Code

```
$(window).load(function () {
    WindowLoad();
});

function WindowLoad() {
    alert($("#test").width());
}
```

C# Code

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "WindowLoad" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, "WindowLoad();", true);
    }
}

protected void Previous_Click(Object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
    String value = e.PostBackValue;
    if (value == "test")
    {
        imgTest.ImageUrl = IMAGEPATH;
    }
}
```

When the page first loads. The $(window).load gets the height/width of the image just fine because it waits for the image to finish loading onto the page before it displays the width/height.

When you click on the imagepath, it'll do a partial postback. When that occurs, the JS are unbind from the elements. Previous_Click will run first and then the Page_PreRender to register the JS on the elements. This is where I need to make sure I get the height/width of the image again. So that JS can do some recalculations. On the partial postback, the results ends up being 0. I do notice that the UpdatePanel takes a while to update the image path, so they may have some cause as to why the results become 0, but I would assume the UpdatePanel will finish loading everything first before trying to run the WindowLoad function.

Comment: Could you add some of your code that you are using or have tried into the question?

Comment: [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx) _Enables sections of a page to be partially rendered **without a postback**._ Confused by your 1st and 2nd sentence (expected behavior).

Comment: UpdatePanel does a partial postback. Not a whole page refresh.